# Setting the width of the GridLayout columns

Tags: java, layout, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have  a `GridLayout` inside a `Composite` and I have two column inside that. I want to have column width 75 % and 25 % of the `Shell` width . How to do that?

Comment: That's not really easy to achieve with `GridLayout`, but there are a lot of other `Layout`s. Have a look at [this](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html), especially the part about `FormLayout`.

Comment: Hi Baz thanks for  the answer.I know about other layout but I want it in grid layout. reason is when  I  resize the shell/composite or move it from  right to left(horizontally) then 2nd column width remains constant until first gets completely collapsed. Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 8):

Right, here you go: Use the `GridData#widthHint` values to force a certain width of the `Composite`s. Compute the width based on the width of the `Shell`:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = Display.getDefault();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

    Composite left = new Composite(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    Composite right = new Composite(shell, SWT.BORDER);

    final GridData leftData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
    final GridData rightData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);

    left.setLayoutData(leftData);
    right.setLayoutData(rightData);

    shell.addListener(SWT.Resize, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
        {
            Point size = shell.getSize();

            leftData.widthHint = (int) (size.x * 0.75);
            rightData.widthHint = size.x - leftData.widthHint;

            System.out.println(leftData.widthHint + " + " + rightData.widthHint + " = " + size.x);
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    shell.layout();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

After start:

[image]

After resizing:

[image]

Comment: Hi Baz thanks for the answer. my ques was bit wrong . after re sizing second column width should not get change at all . suppose in the beginning column width is 400 pixel and after re sizing it should remain 400 but first column width may change upto 0 but second column length should not get change. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Jack That should be easy enough to change on your own, right ;) ? If not, let me know and I can update my answer.

Comment: @ Baz Thanks for your time and response. I got it.